# Converting webm and wav to mp4 in C#

Tags: .net, format, media, wav, webm

I have a web server that needs to get:
- A video blob in webm format (only video)
- An audio blob in wav format

And combine them into an mp4 video (with audio included).

The web server is written in C#.

Any ideas for a free (for commercial use) api that can help?

Comment: I ended up using ffmpeg, wrapped it with a dll and used it on the server side. It'a not ideal since instead of passing the video and audio as byte arrays or streams, I had to actually write them to the file system, invoke ffmpeg, read the result from the file system and return it. Perhaps there's a better .net api for ffmpeg but I couldn't find a reliable one. If anybody has a better idea I'll be happy to hear it